# Laravel - add row foreach date between dates

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent, store

Here I have code that store my `$auction` into auction database:

```
public function store(Requests\OfferRequest $request)
    {

            $auction= new Auction($request->all());

            Auth::user()->auctions()->save($auction);
}
```

Now I from request get $from and $to fields:

```
$auction->from //return me start date for auction
$auction->to // return me end date for auction
```

Now I want to store into `maxoffers` database - rows, foreach date between '`from`' and '`to`' and this rows just to have `auction_id = $auction->id;` and `price = $auction->price` ... other fields to be empty...

How I can do that? So how to make foreach date between `from` and `to` and store id of auction and price from request...

Comment: Can I see your database structure?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PqEHQl2.png

Comment: @Andrew did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple.

```
$start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($auction->from);
$end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($auction->to);


    while(!$start_date->eq($end_date))
    {
        $temp = new maxoffers;
        $temp->id = $auction->id;
        $temp->price = $auction->price;

        //$temp->something_else = 'value';
        //If Your structure does not support null values then you must define some values here.

        $temp->save()

        $start_date->addDay();
    }
```